# Angular: Pass parameters to NgModule

Tags: angular

I have modules that use `TranslateModule` from `ngx-translate` (the question is not about this lib but about Angular). It looks something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/todos/', '.json'),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true
    })
  ]
})
export class TodosModule {
}
```

Now there are 5 modules that look like this one. I decided to move `TranslateModule` to `SharedModule`. But here is a problem: I have to set a path for each module individually (for ex. `./assets/i18n/todos`). That's what I found:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {

  static forChild(i18path: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TranslateModule,
          useValue: TranslateModule.forChild({
            loader: {
              provide: TranslateLoader,
              useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `./assets/i18n/${i18nPath}/`, '.json'),
              deps: [HttpClient]
            },
            isolate: true
          })
        }
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

But it doesn't work. `TranslateHttpLoader` does not load translation files. No errors in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the issue is not so much passing the parameter to `SharedModule`. As far as I know, you're doing it right. You're passing a parameter called `i18path` which is a string. The problem might be that you're trying to pass a module (`TranslateModule`) as a `provider` inside the `forChild` static method, and not as an `import` which is it would normally be. As far as I know, this method must return a `ModuleWithProviders`, and `ModuleWithProviders` doesn't accept `imports`. Here's an example of (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rg5kfu) how you can perfectly pass providers though.

Comment: @RTYX, thanks for the answer, but I have to pass the parameter to imports somehow. That's a requirement of `ngx-translate` library that I use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to import `TranslateModule.forChild(...)` into `SharedModule`, but provide `TranslateLoader` inside `SharedModule#forChild` method:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      isolate: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {

  static forChild(i18nPath: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `./assets/i18n/${i18nPath}/`, '.json'),
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `./assets/i18n/${i18nPath}/`, '.json'),
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
}),
```

to the app.module.

In your shared module just import and export TranslateModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [TranslateModule, ...],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [TranslateModule, ..]
})
export class SharedModule {
```

Comment: I need to take a value of `i18nPath` in the `./assets/i18n/${i18nPath}/`.

Comment: I'm sorry should have read your question more precisely. Can't you get any hint in the network tab or doesn't it try to get the file at all?