# Conditional importing/overriding module imports

Tags: angular

I want to propagate a module config from one module to another. I find this difficult to explain in more detail so I'll try with an example.

I have a module that goes something like:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ButtonComponent,
    TranslatePipe,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ButtonComponent,
  ],
})
export class ButtonModule {
  static withConfig(config: ButtonModuleConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ButtonModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TranslateService,
          useClass: config.translateService,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

And I want to do something like this is another module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ButtonModule, // the one defined above without overriding the TranslateService
  ],
  exports: [
    PageComponent,
  ],
})
export class PageModule {
  static withConfig(config: PageModuleConfig): ??? {
    return {
      ngModule: PageModule,
      imports: [
        ButtonModule.withConfig({
           translateService: config.translateService,
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Is there a thing like `ModuleWithProviders` but more like `ModuleWithImports`?

Thanks!

Comment: Some days ago I find similar post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606967/angular-pass-parameters-to-ngmodule Maybe, it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

If you make your page module to provide value for translate service it will work.

```
export class PageModule {
  static withConfig(config: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: PageModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TranslateService,
          useValue: config.translateService
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwd4xc) stackblitz application.

Comment: Your sample is default. Correct your sample.

Comment: Ah sorry forget to hit save button.